# How did Norris get infected with the alien in the movie "The Thing"?

Tags: the-thing-1982

How did Norris get infected, or is the movie "not clear"? Also could it be a plot device to ratchet up the tension between the characters in an already volatile situation that blows up?

What I am asking is:

1. Is the non mentioning of how he got infected a plot thing that will serve a later purpose?
2. Was this an omission because of time constraints?

Comment: Related: [Infection timelines of John Carpenter's The Thing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/527/49), especially [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36241/49) that seems to support your deductions about adding to the tension.

Comment: Also closely related (if not dupe): [Who gets infected first in John Carpenter's The Thing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95010/98028). The "shadow on the wall" could have been Palmer (intended) or Norris (also plausible). And yeah, obviously, the off-screen happenings are definitely meant to build up the tension :)

Comment: I know it's an old film but I think it would be better to remove the spoiler from the title.

Comment: Voting to close as dupe; one of the answers to the question @Buzz has suggested notes that Carpenter chose not to make all the infections explicit, to help ratchet up the fear and paranoia.